# How to replace a block of code between two patterns with blank lines?

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I am trying  replace a block of code between two patterns with blank lines
Tried using below command

```
sed '/PATTERN-1/,/PATTERN-2/d' input.pl
```

But it only removes the lines between the patterns

PATTERN-1 : "=head"
PATTERN-2 : "=cut"

input.pl contains below text

```
=head
hello
hello world
world
morning
gud
=cut
```

Required output :

```
=head





=cut
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `perl -pe'$f=/^=head/../^=cut/;$_=$/if$f>1&&$f!~/E/'`

Comment: `perl -pe'$_=$/if$f&&=!/^=cut/;$f||=/^=head/'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/=cut/{f=0} {print (f ? "" : $0)} /=head/{f=1}' file
=head





=cut
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the given `sed` command, try

```
$ sed '/=head/,/=cut/{//! s/.*//}' ip.txt
=head





=cut
```

- `//!` to match other than start/end ranges, might depend on `sed` implementation whether it dynamically matches both the ranges or statically only one of them. Works on `GNU sed`

  - `s/.*//` to clear these lines

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/=cut/{found=0}found{print "";next}/=head/{found=1}1' infile

# OR
# ^ to take care of line starts with regexp
awk '/^=cut/{found=0}found{print "";next}/^=head/{found=1}1' infile
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/=cut/{                    # if line contains regexp 
        found=0                 # set variable found = 0
     }
     found{                     # if variable found is nonzero value
       print "";                # print ""
       next                     # go to next line
     }
     /=head/{                   # if line contains regexp
       found=1                  # set variable found = 1
     }1                         # 1 at the end does default operation
                                # print current line/row/record
   ' infile
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
=head
hello
hello world
world
morning
gud
=cut

$ awk '/=cut/{found=0}found{print "";next}/=head/{found=1}1' infile
=head





=cut
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, tried ur command, working as expected. Can u please explain how this command works...please

Comment: @Sanchu explained

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/=head/,/=cut/{//!z}' file
```

Zap the lines between `=head` and `=cut`.